# SQL Server error with HAVING

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the SQL query, but I get this error. Can someone please help me and say me why?

```
SELECT [Item No_],
    [Description],
    [Posting Date]
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Item Ledger Entry] 
WHERE  [Entry Type] = 0 
    AND ([Posting Date] > '" & request.form("from") & "' 
    AND [Posting Date] < '" & request.form("to") & "') " 
HAVING count([Item No_]) = 1
```

I know the SQL injection danger in my code - but now, it is only a test code, and not published.

I get this error:
Column 'Navision4.dbo.3S Company A_S$Item Ledger Entry.Item No_' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i Use SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT max([Item No_]),
  count([Item No_])
  [Description],
  [Posting Date]
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[3S Company A_S$Item Ledger Entry] 
WHERE  [Entry Type] = 0
  AND ([Posting Date] > '" & request.form("from") & "'
  AND [Posting Date] < '" & request.form("to") & "') " 
GROUP BY [Description],[Posting Date]
HAVING count([Item No_]) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks!. I have tried this, and it works whitout errors. But the output are not correct. I still get rows where there are more that 1 rows for [Item No_] in the table.

Comment: This will make more clear which Item No_ has one row.

Comment: Could you paste some example which lines are not ok?